# Problem of map function when try to add conditions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get data from the backend and display it in the frontend. This is the code that I tried to do this task.

```
function Posts() {

    const [notes, getNotes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        getAllNotes();
    }, []);

    const getAllNotes = async () => {
        await axios.get(`/buyerPosts`)
            .then ((response)=>{
                const allNotes=response.data.existingPosts;
                getNotes(allNotes);
            })
            .catch(error=>console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
    }
    console.log(notes);

    const buyerId=(localStorage.getItem("userId"));
    console.log(buyerId);

    const [offers, getOffers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        getAllOffers();
    }, []);

    const getAllOffers = async () => {
        await axios.get(`/viewPendingSellerOffers`)
            .then ((response)=>{
                const allNotes=response.data.existingOffers;
                getOffers(allNotes);
            })
            .catch(error=>console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
    }
    console.log(offers);

    const wasteItem = offers?.filter(wasteItem => wasteItem.status==='accepted' && wasteItem.buyerId===buyerId && wasteItem.wasteItemsListId==='completePost');
    console.log(wasteItem);

    return(
        <main className="grid-b">
            {notes.map((note,index)=> {
                if(wasteItem.find(o=>o.postId !== note._id) !== undefined)
                    return (
                    <article>
                        <div className="text-b">
                            <h3>Post ID: {index + 1}</h3>
                            <p>Location: {note.address}</p>
                            <p>Post Type: {note.postType}</p>
                            <p>Address: {note.address}</p>
                            <p>Telephone No: {note.contact}</p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    );
            })}
        </main>
    );
}

export default Posts;
```

I call the first API and get a length 7 array of objects. This is an image of this array.

[image: First API call results]

Then I call the second API and get a length 6 array of objects. This is an image of this array.

[image: second API call results]

Then I try filter function to results of second API call `const wasteItem = offers?.filter(wasteItem => wasteItem.status==='accepted' && wasteItem.buyerId===buyerId && wasteItem.wasteItemsListId==='completePost');` and get length 2 array of objects.

[image: Results of filter function]

Then I try to map the results using the map function. In the map function, I want only to map 5 items according to the above results. It means first API call I get 7 objects and through the filter function, I get 2 objects so I want to remove those 2 objects data from the mapping. To do this I add the if condition like this `if(wasteItem.find(o=>o.postId !== note._id) !== undefined)`. But it mapping all the 7 items that are in the results of first API call. When I change if condition like this `if(wasteItem.find(o=>o.postId === note._id) !== undefined)` it maps 2 items that get from the above filter function. How do I solve this problem and map only 5 items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concept is mostly nearby. Just little bit change -

```
if(!wasteItem.find(o=>o.postId === note._id))
```

Answer (score 2):

You just update condition like this:

```
if(wasteItem.find(o=>o.postId === note._id) === undefined)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understood the problem correctly, but if I did:

```
{notes.map((note,index)=> {
                const item = wasteItem.find(o=>o.postId === note._id)
                return !item && (
                    <article>
                        <div className="text-b">
                            <h3>Post ID: {index + 1}</h3>
                            <p>Location: {note.address}</p>
                            <p>Post Type: {note.postType}</p>
                            <p>Address: {note.address}</p>
                            <p>Telephone No: {note.contact}</p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    );
            })}
```

Should solve the problem. Or, alternatively you can do:

```
{notes.filter(note => !wasteItem.some(item => item.postId === note._id)).map((note,index)=>  (
                    <article>
                        <div className="text-b">
                            <h3>Post ID: {index + 1}</h3>
                            <p>Location: {note.address}</p>
                            <p>Post Type: {note.postType}</p>
                            <p>Address: {note.address}</p>
                            <p>Telephone No: {note.contact}</p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    );
         )}
```

which will will filter out the notes, which are included in the wasteItem array before mapping.